# eclipse + Scene Builder 2 + JFXtras : how?

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am using latest eclipse (Luna) together with e(fx)clipse 1.0 to build a non-trivial application.
I am using maven to build it, so binaries can be found in the .../target/ subdir.

I seem unable to use Scene Builder when non-standard widgets are used.
I understand this should be a classpath problem, but I am unable to finf the right spell.

I tried something along the lines:

```
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../../target/classes?>
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../../target/jfx/native/com.voith.hyconmde.ui-1.0.8-jfx.jar?>
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../../../../../../.m2/repository/org/jfxtras/jfxtras-labs/8.0-r2-SNAPSHOT/jfxtras-labs-8.0-r2-SNAPSHOT.jar?>
<?import com.voith.hyconmde.ui.TreePane?>
<?import jfxtras.labs.scene.control.BreadcrumbBar?>
```

but this does NOT work (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.voith.hyconmde.ui.TreePane`).
All references can be accessed in the named paths relative to position of .fxml file.

Is there some way to get the "right path" directly from eclipse? After all JavaFX Preview seems able to handle classpath in the correct way.